# Css hover function not working because of zindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason my hover function is not working and i am sure its because of z index. However i need it so that i can use javascript and for it to hover over the box. Any help on this would be great.

Code:

```
.hello :hover {
    background-color: Green;
    color: blue;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the z-index. It's with the typing of `.hello :hover`. The space removes the `:hover` effect, because of child functions. Instead, write `.hello:hover`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKVC7/66/)

Comment: No problem; everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to `.hello`

and change `.hello :hover` to `.hello:hover`

Comment: Got to it just a second before me :)